# No wifi found ubuntu 18.04 lts Centrino Advanced-N 6230

Tags: networking, wireless, ubuntu-drivers

been typing commands found on web a could not make it to work

sudo lshw -class network   returns

```
network NO RECLAMADO
       descripción: Network controller
       producto: Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak]
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:08:00.0
       versión: 34
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuración: latency=0
       recursos: memoria:b5900000-b5901fff

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 8: ignoring bad line starting with '“options'
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:0091] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 AGN [8086:5221]
    Kernel modules: wl
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
gerardo@gerardo-XPS-L412Z:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
gerardo@gerardo-XPS-L412Z:~$ uname -a
Linux gerardo-XPS-L412Z 5.3.0-51-generic #44~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 23 14:27:18 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
“options iwlwifi disable_msix=1”

gerardo@gerardo-XPS-L412Z:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:0091] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 AGN [8086:5221]
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [1028:0522]
gerardo@gerardo-XPS-L412Z:~$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep -E 'vermagic | intree'
gerardo@gerardo-XPS-L412Z:~$ 

gerardo@gerardo-XPS-L412Z:~$ grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:remove iwlwifi \
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf.save: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf.save:# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf.save:# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf.save:# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf.save:remove iwlwifi \
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf.save:(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf.save:“options iwlwifi disable_msix=1”
```

Comment: Upgrade kernel to HWE. `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04`

Comment: network NO RECLAMADO
       descripción: Network controller
       producto: Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak]
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:08:00.0
       versión: 34
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: bus_master cap_list
       configuración: latency=0
       recursos: memoria:b5900000-b5901fff

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; uname -a` terminal command.

Comment: You have a broken `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file. Please add output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` to your question.

Comment: Please add output of `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and `grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: But the easiest way would be to do a fresh install of 18.04.4. It will work out of the box.

Comment: install over it? will i keep my things?

Comment: i can try version 20.04 ...

Comment: Any version will work. You just broke this one.

Comment: Thank you! sorry for my english, is not my first language.  Only I can break ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

You have a broken `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file.

Run `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and remove the line

```
“options iwlwifi disable_msix=1”
```

Ctrl+O to save, Ctrl+X to exit.

The option is wrong and the quotes are wrong.

I wonder where so many people get this crap? There is no `disable_msix` option in `iwlwifi`.

Reboot and Wi-Fi should work.

Also I suggest to run

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

This will remove Broadcom drivers that are not relevant.

Comment: Could you fix your system eventually @Gerardo ?